# About 'a, an, the' to introduce company

Tags: grammar, articles

my name is Ashok Choudhary. My company name is 'Expert'. I want to introduce my company by advertisement and I also want to show my name with my company. Which one is right

> (1) Expert, An ashok choudhary co.

> (2) Expert, A Ashok choudhary co.

> (3) Expert, Ashok choudhary co.

Comment: What is the context.  Are you speaking to someone, or are you writing your company name at the top of a letter, or something else.    Take care to use capital letters correctly.  You have missed the capital letters in your name and perhaps your company name.  You can [edit] to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The only expression with a correct use of English is "Expert. An Ashok Choudhary company".  This suggests that it is one of many companies that you run.  (Company is rarely abbreviated except in forms like ".... co. ltd.")

The overall impression is odd.  You don't see adverts for "Microsoft. A Bill Gates company".  The only reason you would do this is that you believe your name is so respected that people will only respond to the advert if they see your respected name next to it. (And unless you are the Building and Construction Minister of Bihar, you aren't the most famous person with the name Ashok Choudhary)

So my I would prefer a description of your company to the name of the person who founded it. For example "Expert. We provide technical solutions to software problems"  Or just "Expert"  You don't really need anything else.